# Using FFmpeg can I merge three different videos using overlap and overlay in one instance?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm quite new to FFmpeg, so please bear with me.

I find myself in a situation where I have:

1. An intro video
2. A main video
3. An outro video

Desired effect:

The intro video has an alpha channel that at the end functions as a transition as it reveals the main video. An overlap in the concatenation would help this happen.

The last 20 seconds of the main video need to have the frame scaled down and overlaid in a corner of the outro video.

Also important to note that the main video has different language audio channels, so I would like to create a merged output for every channel.

What is the procedure?
Is this possible to do in one instance or in one go?